# Split Crystal Report Details Section into 2 Parts

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that I want to split the details section in two vertically. I have 2 queries that each take 2 parameters.

One command takes previous years start and end dates,
Second command takes current years start and end dates.

[image]

The queries are similar however when I place the on the same line in the details section, the rows start repeating themselves. See image below.

[image]

How can I get to place the 2 query results on the same details section and be independent without the repitition?

Comment: In report selection formula write something like `{CashFlowLeft.SAP Code} = {CashFlowRight.SAP Code}`; maybe you have to account for missing codes (null values) either.

Comment: That helps. Problem comes when previous dates have no data, the current (right side) report becomes blank because of null values. Will fix this from the query side.

Comment: You could create single query from both queries, using full outer join or something - this way you don't have fiddle with crystal formulas. Crystal Reports doesn't handle independent commands/queries very well.

Comment: Went with your full outer join option. Thanks.

Comment: why not use 2 subreports and deal with them individual. That way u will have a lot of flexbility